# Obsolete questions

Tags: feature-request, questions

I was search for a node.js question, when I found one question and think ah! that it , I change all my code and doesn't work , I back to Stack Overflow to read better the answers, I follow to other question , when I read the bug was fixed in version for example 0.6 the code  behavior isn't already need that etc, on newer version of node.js (I use a version of 3 years later) so I realize that I have to undo all changes that I made in first assumption.

Bottom line shouldn't this question marked was obsolete, for a user notice that are reading a old question and perhaps outdated . And avoid reading things that aren't true anymore

Examples: 
[Adding a hook to globally log all node HTTP responses in node.js / express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719626/adding-a-hook-to-globally-log-all-node-http-responses-in-node-js-express/14093047#14093047)

[node.js https no response 'end' event, 'close' instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537510/node-js-https-no-response-end-event-close-instead)

Comment: Do you personally have the time to manually go through all of the node.js tagged questions to decide if they're obsolete or not? What about those users who still have to use an older version of node.js for some reason that need the information? How would you go about implementing deciding which of the millions of questions and answers here are obsolete or not?

Comment: An answer correct at the time is often still correct for the specific technology/functions used at that time. Generic questions often get closed for "too broad" etc, so a specific system/function etc is usually given and thus still a relevant and correct Q&A for it. Example: using `mysql_query()` is now depreciated, so a Q "How should I query a DB" is likely now out of date if `mysql_query()` was an answer, however, that would have been closed anyway, so as said would have likely had specifically been a Q with `mysql_query()` in it.

Comment: @Ken White , no I don't have time, but we can begin with zero question with the flag , and adding case by case (with help of all users) , for example I go to an question like I mention in here, and write or click: "I propose this question should be marked as obsoleted." and it could be like that , is not mandatory have defined if is obsolete or not

Comment: You have not addressed the other parts of my comment; you've only partially answered the first question. We can begin with the premise that you're not the only user here, and there are others that may need information you feel you don't. You should **always** test an answer for validity/correctness before changing your own code to use it. That's *your* responsibility, and if you choose to apply untested changes to your code that's on you. By just flagging them, you're putting more work onto moderators or other users for no reason. Obsolete information still may have value to someone.

Comment: I though that I had reply to all questions here, mark as obsolete is different of delete it , so question still be available, other point was I can improve my searchs to get better results , add or removing obsolete questions.

Comment: about how to decide if it is obsolete or not, I already answered "when is not about last version and may be not correct anymore " .
I'm not proposed delete it I'm proposing flag it , for better and quick understanding if we are looking for the correct source

Answer (score 8):

If an answer was never correct, it ought to be downvoted. If an answer was correct initially but is no longer, the proper way to handle this would be to add a comment to the incorrect answer explaining that it was no longer correct. As Ken White mentioned in the comments, an answer which still describes an issue that someone using an older framework version might encounter is still useful to some people. You can make it more valuable by clarifying the conditions under which it does and doesn't currently apply.

Comment: OK , but what is the problem marked it as obsolete ? I don't mean delete it . I would help both cases , who is looking for question for older framework , and also help who is looking for newest framework .

Comment: What does obsolete mean though? A clear comment which explains the scenarios under which the answer is and isn't obsolete is far more useful than an "obsolete" flag which would potentially leave someone still having to research at what point it became obsolete.

Comment: when is not about last version and may not be correct anymore